# Can't able to fetch specific values from mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a newbie at node.js. I am trying to fetch values from a collection by a specific name. But Im getting null values.

This is in my controller.js.

```
 var Product = require('.././model/product');
 var Bill = require('.././model/bill');
 saveBill: function(request, response) {
    var loginUser = request.session.user;
    var bill = new Bill({
        product: request.body.product,
    });
    var query = Product.find({ pname: request.body.product });
    query.select('sell CGST SGST');
    query.exec(function (err, product) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log('%d   %s    %s.', product.sell, product.CGST,
          product.SGST);
      });
}
```

This is my product Schema

```
    var product = new Schema({
    brand:{type: String, required: [true, '{PATH} is required']},
    pname: {type: String, required: [true, '{PATH} is required']},
    serialno: {type: String, required: [true, '{PATH} is required'] },
    buy: {type: Number, min: [0, 'Can not be a negative value'], required: [true, '{PATH} is required']},
    sell: {type: Number, min: [0, 'Can not be a negative value'], required: [true, '{PATH} is required']},
    CGST: {type: String, required: [true, '{PATH} is required'] },
    SGST: {type: String, required: [true, '{PATH} is required'] }
});
```

I want to fetch sell, cgst and sgst values from a specific product and do some calculation in the bill and store a result in the bill schema. I'm little confused how to do that. And That `request.body.product` may contain multiple values. Should I have to do anything different for that? Hoping to get some help, thanks in advance...

Comment: are you getting correct values in request.body?

Comment: Yes, I did try to console.log the req.body value and It was getting the correct value.